# $\LaTeX$ in Comments Not Displayed on First Page Load

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

Over the last month or so, I've noticed that the $\LaTeX$ in the comments section is, more often than not, not displayed **at all** on the first page load $($i.e., it is completely missing, as opposed to being shown in plain text form, but not properly rendered$)$. One has to refresh the browser for it to even become visible in the first place. Does anyone else have this problem ? $($I run *Mozilla Firefox* $44$ under *Windows XP SP* $3).$

Comment: Windows XP? That's terrible.

Comment: You're not the only one :-/

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, I know... :-$($ What I **really** wanted was *Windows $98$ SE*, but unfortunately it can *neither* recognize hard drives larger than a certain size, *nor* work with *NTFS*, for that matter. On the bright side, it's stable, up to date, and I also chose the *Windows Classic Style* and *Classic Start Menu* option to bring back some of that *retro* outlook.

Comment: If that's sarcasm, it's not strong enough.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well, why exactly do you consider it so “terrible” in the first place ? :-\ It's obviously *far* smaller than the other versions $($which is a huge advantage, since I'm always in need of free space on the hard drive$),$ it is very stable, and has all I need, and more...

Comment: It's very not up to date, the support was dropped a few years ago. Much to the dismay of many Vista haters (as Vista stunk to high heavens). And it's not that stable either. How about a nice Linux system instead? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I just meant that I keep it updated. $($Updates still appear from time to time$).$ I've never had any security problems $($the antivirus is constantly updated, hence no need for Linux$)$, there is nothing meaningful that newer systems have to offer, and I also personally dislike the outlook of both Linux, as well as newer versions of Windows $($the latter remind me of old UNIX versions$).$ Vista looked nice, but it was also self-destructive, to the point where I had to reinstall it several times. The newer versions are stable, but unfortunately also much bigger and inaesthetic.

Comment: Well. Good luck, then.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: But seriously, what do you find so “irresistible” about newer versions, or other operating systems, such as Linux ?

Comment: I want my computer to do what I tell it to do. Not what Microsoft taught it to think that I want it to do instead (which often times is not what I wanted it to do). The fact I have to use Windows on my tablet is a travesty, but it has redeeming qualities (like a Wacom support for the pen).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm a computer programmer, so for me that's usually not an impediment.